# If the suffix field is present, it should be appended enclosed in parenthesis

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Write an SQL query to get the list of customers' full names with their countries and phone numbers.

The customer full name is a space-delimited concatenation of the title (if it exists), first_name, and last_name fields. If the suffix field is present, it should be appended enclosed in parenthesis. In other words, output the full name in the following format:

```
<title> <first_name> <last_name> (suffix)
```

Output phone numbers in the following format:

```
<phone_country_code>-<phone_area_code>-<phone_number>
```

Be sure to include all customers, even if they are missing some information

Sort the results alphabetically by country and then by phone number in ascending order within each country.

[image]

I have tried the code below but I cannot figure out how to put the parenthesis around suffix if exists and it is not ordering by phone num.

```
select CONCAT(c.title,' ' ,c.first_name, ' ',c.last_name,' ',c.suffix) AS "full name", pa.country,
concat(p.phone_country_code, '-', p.phone_area_code, '-', p.phone_number) as "phone number"
from customer as c 
  left join customer_address AS ca on c.customer_id = ca.customer_id 
  left join physical_address AS pa on  ca.physical_address_id = pa.physical_address_id
  left join phone_number as p on c.customer_id = p.customer_id

order by pa.country, p.phone_number asc
```

Comment: [`CONCAT_WS(' ',c.title,c.first_name,c.last_name,'('||c.suffix||')')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) Both `CONCAT()` and `CONCAT_WS()` skip all null fields. `||` concatenation operator results in a null if any of the elements is null, so the parenthesis will be nullified if the field's `null`. [Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/verwZLdu)

Comment: thank You, do you know why the code isnt ordering by phone number?

Comment: It should be. It should order by country and if you have multiple records with the same country, it should list them next to each other, ordered by the phone number. That seems to be the requirement. If that doesn't work, please add some example data (as text or even as `insert` statements) for your tables and the result you're getting, explaining what you expected instead and why.

Answer (score 1):

1)You can use Concatenation Operator ( || ) instead of concat() function.

2)When some of your columns have also null values you can use coalesce() which keeps the null fields. It's `coalesce(mytext,'')` when your column is a type character or `coalesce(mynumber,0)` if you use numeric types.  You can see examples [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-coalesce/).

I think you want something like that:

```
select coalesce(c.title,'')||' '||c.first_name||' '||c.last_name||' '||coalesce(c.suffix,'') AS full_name
, pa.country,
p.phone_country_code||'-'||p.phone_area_code||'-'||p.phone_number as phone_number
from customer as c 
  left join customer_address AS ca on c.customer_id = ca.customer_id 
  left join physical_address AS pa on  ca.physical_address_id = pa.physical_address_id
  left join phone_number as p on c.customer_id = p.customer_id

order by pa.country, p.phone_number asc
```